# How to save .mxd programatically?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, c#

How do I save a .mxd programatically? The project is never saved and on button-click, I want to save the project.

I use `SaveFileDialog` to get the filepath and then use the following:

```
IMapDocument mapDocument= ArcMap.Document as IMapDocument;
mapDocument.SaveAs(projectPath);
```

This crashes my ArcMap. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any error message or log file?

Comment: Can you confirm what the variable projectpath is?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to achieve results as following:

```
public void SaveProject()
{
    UID uid = new UIDClass();
    //uid.Value = "{119591DB-0255-11D2-8D20-080009EE4E51}"; 
    uid.Value = "esriArcMapUI.MxFileMenuItem";
    uid.SubType = 3;
    ICommandItem item = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars.Find(uid, false);
    item.Execute();      
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

you sure obtain IApplication/IMxApplication hook somehow in your code then you can obtain 
IMxDocument pointer and then cast it to IMapDocument:

```
IMxDocument ipMxDoc=(IMxApplication)ipApp;

//Suppose ipApp has been obtained via hook passed in OnCreate method of ICommand interface

IMapDocument ipMapDoc=(IMapDocument)ipMxDoc;

ipMapDoc.SaveAs(fileName);
//Suppose fileName obtained from a SaveDialogBox
```